# How does the VALUE? function work?

Tags: undefined, scope, rebol, rebol3

I have reduced down to a small example some code that I have, which tests for whether a variable called `class-name` has a value assigned to it:

```
ask-params: function [
    config-file [file!]
    default-class-name
    default-fields
] [
    probe value? 'class-name
    input
    either (value? 'class-name) [
        probe class-name
    ] [
        ;-- omit code in this branch for now
    ]
]

ret-block: ask-params %simple-class.params.txt "Person" "First Name, Last Name"
```

The expression `value? 'class-name` returns false here.  On the other hand, if I fill in the missing branch with an assignment:

```
ask-params: function [
    config-file [file!]
    default-class-name
    default-fields
] [
    probe value? 'class-name
    input
    either (value? 'class-name) [
        probe class-name
    ] [
        class-name: default-class-name
    ]
]

ret-block: ask-params %simple-class.params.txt "Person" "First Name, Last Name"
```

This will return true for `value? 'class-name`.  But in this second case, `class-name: default-class-name` isn't even executed yet.

I would think that class-name shouldn't exist in memory, so `value? 'class-name` should be returning false.  Why is `value?` returning true instead?

Comment: This is a clear question for any rebolers, if you are not a reboler skip this instead of just voting down what you are not capable to understand.

Comment: Maybe you should ask "Why does -part 1- return false but -part 2- return true?"  It probably isn't weird behavior at all.

Comment: SURE IT IS WEIRD because class-name: default-class-name isn't even executed yet so class-name shouldn't exist in memory and so value? 'class-name should not return true.

Comment: The point is "is this weird" is not a good question. "Why does this happen" or "How does this work" are good questions.

Comment: Rex: Yes, that was my point.  Rebol:  I was trying to explain why someone downvoted you.

Comment: If people were machines I would maybe more explicit but I guess that some human brains are capable to understand that they should of course elicit the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `function`.  This scans the body of the function and pre-creates the local variables for you, initialized to NONE.  That's why `value? 'class-name` becomes true (because NONE is a legal value for a variable, distinct from the situation of being "unset").

If you used `func` instead, then both would return false.

Comment: Ah that's it. But this should be considered a bug because that is not the expected behavior of a function. funct shouldn't behave differently from func except for the variables being turned local.

So I have to return to func and declare all my variables local just because funct not behaves like a true function ? That defeats the purpose of having created funct.

Comment: funct is syntactic sugar for func /local.
It scans the body of the function for you looking for set-words, and creates them as /local. If you declare them with /local, the effect is the same.

Comment: I don't think it should be considered a bug, because it cannot work any other way. Remember that in REBOL, the only context that can be expanded dynamically is the global one. In your case, the behavior is exactly as expected: a context is created and words are bound to it.

Comment: It's a bug because it doesn't behave as a user would expect or it should documented explicitely and says: it's impossible to use value? with funct.

Comment: I mean doc implicitely says funct behaves exactly like func /local. but that is not the case. And I'm not interested in using funct if value? and maybe other functions don't work exactly as with func /local.

Comment: /local is daunting because you have to not forget to add local vars but I prefer that rather than realize I need to use it finally just because I need to use value? function.

Comment: So funct sucks I'll never use it :)

Comment: `funct` behaves exactly like `func /local`. You can read the source to confirm this. Or you can show an example where they behave differently. So far you seem to have done neither.

Answer (score 1):

Here I show you two examples not using FUNCTION, but otherwise equivalent to your code:

```
ask-params: func [config-file [file!] default-class-name default-fields] [
    probe value? 'class-name
    input
    either (value? 'class-name) [
        probe class-name
    ][
    ]
]

ask-params: func [
    config-file [file!] default-class-name default-fields /local class-name
] [
    probe value? 'class-name
    input
    either (value? 'class-name) [
        probe class-name
    ][
    ]
]
```

While the `value?` function in the first example yields `#[false]`, in the second example it yields `#[true]`. That is because the "refinement arguments" following an "unused refinement" (a refinement that is not used in the actual call) are initialized to `#[none!]` together with the refinement variable. This applies to the `/local` variables as well, since the `/local` refinement does not differ from other function refinements (except for the fact, that it is a convention to use it to define local variables).

Since the `function` generator uses the `/local` method to implement local variables "under the hood", the above description applies to all functions it generates as well.

Comment: Thanks ladislav I know about /local but it's so daunting to add to /local each time you add an other variable so that you forget to do it. Now I finally prefer func and /local if funct is not able to behave exactly like func /local.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, which avoids using FUNC/LOCAL and still allows the use of FUNCTION.

That is to not use a SET-WORD! for the assignment.  Instead use the SET function on a LIT-WORD!

```
ask-params: function [config-file [file!] default-class-name default-fields] [
    probe value? 'class-name
    input
    either (value? 'class-name) [
        probe class-name
    ] [
        set 'class-name default-class-name
    ]
]
```

You will get `#[false]` for the `value?` function.  However, the call to SET will be setting `class-name` in the global environment...not as a local.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav but it doesn't change the fact that I cannot use funct and so funct is useless for me. Either funct is a shortcut for func /local either it isn't and for me it isn't in my very example.

Comment: It is as *my very example* proves

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `function` behaves differently than `func /local`. Look at these examples:

```
>> f: func [/x] [value? 'x]
>> f
== true
```

I didn't give any value to x, but it says it HAS a value. Same for /local

```
>> f: func [/local x] [value? 'x]
>> f
== true
```

Because when you make a variable local (or a refinement) then it means you already set a value for it (which is none) and that is what `function` does.

Comment: Well I don't understand why you say it doesn't behave differently since I found an example where it does :)

Comment: But in your first example, there is no set-word, as in your second example: "class-name: default-class-name". funct runs at definition-time not when you call the function. When you use funct and if there is a set-word like "class-name:" then it is already defined as a local variable in your function. Even if you never call the function. And this is exactly the same behavior as func /local.
 If you put class-name as a /local in your func then it will be the same.